# Click EN to change to AR and vice versa

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on the `AR` button it changes to the `EN` button. Then when I click on the `EN` button it doesn't go back to the `AR` button.

This is my code:

```js
function change() {
  if (document.getElementById('AE').value = "AR") {
    document.getElementById('AE').innerHTML = "EN";
    document.getElementById('body').dir = "rtl";
    
    fetch("https://api.npoint.io/abb3ff619eec383b1bb7")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        document.querySelector("#lang").innerText = data.name[0].ara;
      })
  } else {
    document.getElementById('AE').innerHTML = "AR";
    document.getElementById('body').dir = "ltr";
    
    fetch("https://api.npoint.io/abb3ff619eec383b1bb7")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        document.querySelector("#lang").innerText = data.name[0].eng;
      })

  };
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <button style="color:black;" id="AE" onclick="change()">AR</button>
  <div id="lang">Amjad</div>
</body>
```

I want when I click `EN` to change to `AR` and vice versa. How to solve this issues?

Comment: `getElementById('AE').value = "AR"` _assigns_. `getElementById('AE').value === "AR"` _compares_.

Comment: What is the reason for unaccepting the answer? Please let me know if you have any problem with the answer

Answer (score 1):

First use `innerText` instead of `value` of `button`. And then note that in `if` clause you've used `=` instead of `==`.

Here is working snippet:

```js
function change() {
    if (document.getElementById('AE').innerText == "AR") {
        document.getElementById('AE').innerHTML = "EN";
        document.getElementById('body').dir = "rtl";
        fetch("https://api.npoint.io/abb3ff619eec383b1bb7")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                document.querySelector("#lang").innerText = data.name[0].ara;
            })
    } else {
        document.getElementById('AE').innerHTML = "AR";
        document.getElementById('body').dir = "ltr";
        fetch("https://api.npoint.io/abb3ff619eec383b1bb7")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                document.querySelector("#lang").innerText = data.name[0].eng;
            })
    };
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <button  style="color:black;" id="AE"onclick="change()">AR</button>
  <div id="lang">Amjad</div>
</body>
```